# How do I install gprof in MinGW?

Tags: mingw

How do I install 'gprof' in MinGW?

It seems that my MinGW installation manager does not have 'gprof' package.  I have tried to search on google without success.

Comment: Have you used CodeBlocks IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no separate gprof package; gprof is included within the GNU Binutils package, which is a mandatory prerequisite of GCC itself, so if you have correctly installed GCC, you should already have installed gprof.

Comment: You are right.  I find gprof in my installation. My actual problem is wrong PATH environment variable.